# python string replace not working

Tags: python, string, replace

i have a list of list that contains tokens. some of the tokens contain special characters that i want to replace with empty space. However my code didnt work:

```
mylist = [['hi','how','are','you','forward\xcato\xcahearing\xcafrom\xcayou\xcasoon'],
          ['good','morning']]
```

**mycode:**

```
new_list = []
for l in mylist:
    l2 = [i.replace('\xca', ' ') for i in l]
    new_list.append(l2)
new_list[0]
>>> ['hi','how','are','you','forward\xcato\xcahearing\xcafrom\xcayou\xcasoon']
```

Not sure why it didnt work.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.x and that works for me. Output: ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'forward to hearing from you soon']

Comment: im using jupyter notebook

Comment: Also works in Python 2.7.

Comment: @jxn i'm using also Jupyter NB. I have tried with Python 2.7.x kernel and also it works.

Comment: Works on Python 2.7.12

Comment: here is output for `new_list` in python 3.5 :
`[['h', 'i'], ['h', 'o', 'w'], ['a', 'r', 'e'], ['y', 'o', 'u'], ['f', 'o', 'r',
'w', 'a', 'r', 'd', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ',
'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', ' ', 's', 'o', 'o', 'n'], ['hi', 'how',
'are', 'you', 'forward to hearing from you soon'], ['good', 'morning']]`

Comment: i think you should tell us which version of python are you using ?

Comment: Show the output. It works for me with python 2.7.6

Comment: Also works well on python 3.6.0 (without Jupyter NB)

Answer (score 0):

This works in Jupyter too:

```
mylist = [['hi','how','are','you','forward\xcato\xcahearing\xcafrom\xcayou\xcasoon'],
          ['good','morning']]

print ([[sentence.translate(str.maketrans("\xca", " ")) for sentence in item] for item in mylist])
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code will Remove all special characters from your string! not just '\xca' and you will have a trim string. ( No library needs ):

```
your_list = [['hi','how','are','you','forward\xcato\xcahearing\xcafrom\xcayou\xcasoon'],
['good','morning']]


def special_characters_finder(text):

    renew_word = []

    for char in text:
        try:
            char.encode('ascii')

        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            renew_word.append(' ')

        else:
            renew_word.append(char)

    return ''.join(renew_word)


buffer_output = []
for box in your_list:
    for item in box:
        get_list = special_characters_finder(item)
        buffer_output.append(get_list)

print(buffer_output)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'forward to hearing from you soon', 'good', 'morning']
```